Use XHR in Webworker without CORS headers or preflight answer from server
I am working on a page that will be server by a small embedded webserver that I have no control of. On the page, some data transfer (XHR) should be done inside a web worker. The server will not send any cross-origin relevant headers nor will it answer preflight OPTIONS requests reasonably.
When I put the worker javascript code into a separate file, the XHR in the worker do what they should.
But I would like to avoid the need to put two files up to the server. When I put the javascript source of the worker inside the same page and use data:text/javascript;base64,' + btoa(scripttext) for the worker, then the browser will try preflight calls to the server which fails.
What option do I have to have the worker in the same page and still be able to use XHR inside the worker successfully? I.e. how can I get the browser to treat it same-origin? I mean, it is in the same file...
Thanks!
Edit:
The browsers involved are Firefox 115.11.0esr and chromium 125.0.6422.112

This question may be relevant. @Ivar I think this question is not at all the standard "What is a CORS error?" duplicate.

What browser is involved with this problem, and what version?

Hm, it might not even be a "secure context" as per the description of the chromium bug - needless to say the webserver does not support https either

Worker created from a data: URL have an opaque origin (step 4, "origin").
You'll want to generate your worker from a blob: URL instead which will inherit its origin from the owner's one:
Example as a JSfiddle since StackSnippet's null origined frames would make for an odd example:
const workerScript = `
  postMessage(location.origin);
`;
const workerURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([workerScript], { type: "text/javascript" }));
const worker = new Worker(workerURL);
worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => console.log("from worker", data);
console.log("from main", document.origin);
// Would log the same values


I had tried it but had another logic error that prevented it from working. Just do it right and it works. Thanks!
